# Google apps script select specific columns when copying to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to google scripts and I'm trying to copy specific range of columns to another sheet.
This is the code

```
function helpFunction() {
  
 const sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ts = sss.getSheetByName('this');
  const ss = sss.getSheetByName('source');

  const rawData = ss.getRange("A:F").getValues(); // HERE - i just need columns B,C,E,F instead of all from a to f

  const frawData=rawData.filter(row=>row[0]>0);
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, frawData.length, frawData[0].length).setValues(frawData);

}
```

If there's someone who could help me I will be more than glad.

Comment: You mean like this: `const rawData = ss.getRange("B:F").getValues();`?

Comment: kind of, except the D column

Comment: Then just filter it out like so `const rawData = ss.getRange("B:F").getValues().map(row => [ row[0], row[1], row[3], row[4] ]);`

Comment: Let me know if this gets the job done :)

Comment: exactly like this ! thank you a lot.